# linux mint xfce wont keep screen orientation

Tags: linux, screen

I have my laptop setup to a monitor so Whenever Linux mint locks my computer, it changes the orientation of the screens so that my monitor displays my laptop screen and there not side by side. every time this happens I have to set the screens back to normal, can anyone help me fix this?

I tried looking in the settings to fix this, but I couldn't find anything for it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.